# Is it possible to use angular lazy loading without a routes file

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I am using angular lazy loading for my modules.

For example I load the modules like this as recommended by AG8

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, data: {title: 'Home', animation: 'Home'}},
  {path: 'services', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/services.module').then(module => module.ServicesModule), data: {title: 'Services', animation: 'Services'}},
  // {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/login.module').then(module => module.LoginModule), data: {title: 'Login', animation: 'Login'}},
  {path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/dashboard.module').then(module => module.DashboardModule ), data: {title: 'Dashboard', animation: 'Dashboard'}, canActivate: [AppAuthGuard]},
  {path: 'user/:userID/event/:eventID', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/event.module').then(module => module.EventModule ), data: {title: 'Event Details', animation: 'Event'}},
  {path: 'user/:userID', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/user.module').then(module => module.UserModule), data: {title: 'Profile', animation: 'User'}},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

The for each of those modules I have their corresponding files eg:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SomeRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [SomeComponent]
})
export class SomeModule { }
```

But for all those modules I have to create their corresponding router files eg:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SomeComponent
  }
];
```

Is there a way to just guide from the parent module the route to load the lazy module's declared component without having to create a router file?

Something like:

```
loadChildren: () => import('./modules/services.module').then(module => module.ServicesModule.SomeComponent)
```

Comment: Not sure this is what estonished me first with angular. The basic spirit is Single Page Application. a module is a "manager" of components. I don't think this can be achieved. lazy loading is for modules not components. Hope you'll have a different answer but not sure you will

Comment: @JSmith hey thanks a lot yes I am more searching in lazy loading components indeed. These routes illustrated above, are a bit of "heavy" components. But I understand better now with your comment. Thank you.

Comment: https://netbasal.com/the-need-for-speed-lazy-load-non-routable-modules-in-angular-30c8f1c33093